# SPARQL query for three sub-properties does not work

Tags: sparql, rdf, endpoint

I tried to make a SPARQL query but I failed.
I have three properties which I need to ask for like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?locality ?museRes ?calendar ?category
FROM <http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/repo/context/TTT>
WHERE { 
 {
 ?museRes vCard:locality ?locality FILTER (regex(?museRes, "odaia_bunicii", "i")) .
 ?museRes vCard:category ?category FILTER (regex(?museRes, "odaia_bunicii", "i")).
 ?museRes vCard:hasCalendarRequest ?calendar FILTER (regex(?museRes, "odaia_bunicii", "i"))
 }
}
```

in [Romanian OpenData SPARQL endpoint](http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/repo/sparql/admin/squebi.html#?query=PREFIX%20rdf:%20%3Chttp:%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0APREFIX%20vCard:%20%3Chttp:%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2006%2Fvcard%2Fns%23%3E%0APREFIX%20dbPedia:%20%3Chttp:%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20openDataP:%20%3Chttp:%2F%2Fopendata.cs.pub.ro%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20openDataR:%20%3Chttp:%2F%2Fopendata.cs.pub.ro%2Fresource%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20dc:%20%3Chttp:%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20dcmitype:%20%3Chttp:%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fdcmitype%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20dcterms:%20%3Chttp:%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20cdtype:%20%3Chttp:%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fcld%2Fcdtype%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20cld:%20%3Chttp:%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fcld%2Fterms%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20marcrel:%20%3Chttp:%2F%2Fwww.loc.gov%2Floc.terms%2Frelators%2F%3E%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Flocality%20%3FmuseRes%20%3Fcalendar%20%3Fcategory%0AFROM%20%3Chttp:%2F%2Fopendata.cs.pub.ro%2Frepo%2Fcontext%2FTTT%3E%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%7B%0A%20%3FmuseRes%20vCard:locality%20%3Flocality%20FILTER%20(regex(%3FmuseRes,%20%22odaia_bunicii%22,%20%22i%22))%20.%0A%20%3FmuseRes%20vCard:category%20%3Fcategory%20FILTER%20(regex(%3FmuseRes,%20%22odaia_bunicii%22,%20%22i%22)).%0A%20%3FmuseRes%20vCard:hasCalendarRequest%20%3Fcalendar%20FILTER%20(regex(%3FmuseRes,%20%22odaia_bunicii%22,%20%22i%22))%0A%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FmuseRes%0ALIMIT%20100%0A&writer=browse)

The problem is that three properties are part from another three super-properties (dcterms:spatials, dcterms:description and opendata:MuseumTour) and that approach doesn't work. I tried with OPTION operator but it show me only ?museRes and ?locality values even ?calendar and ?category are not empty.

In the end, I tried to use UNION instead of OPTION, but it works only with one UNION and I need to use two UNION operators.

How may I ask for vCard:locality vCard:category and vCard:hasCalendarRequest in the above RDF?

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:marcrel="http://www.loc.gov/loc.terms/relators/"
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:dcmitype="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/"
    xmlns:opendata="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/property/"
    xmlns:vCard="http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#"
    xmlns:dbPedia="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/"
    xmlns:cdtype="http://purl.org/cld/cdtype/"
    xmlns:cld="http://purl.org/cld/terms/">
  <dbPedia:Museum rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/">
    <dcterms:description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Info/">
        <dc:identifier>7172383</dc:identifier>
        <opendata:FoundingYear>2016</opendata:FoundingYear>
        <dc:title xml:lang="en"></dc:title>
        <dcterms:isReferencedBy></dcterms:isReferencedBy>
        <marcrel:OWN>
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Info/Own/">
            <dc:identifier></dc:identifier>
            <dc:title></dc:title>
          </rdf:Description>
        </marcrel:OWN>
        <opendata:Accreditation></opendata:Accreditation>
        <dc:subject>
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Info/Subject/">
            <vCard:value xml:lang="en"></vCard:value>
            <vCard:label xml:lang="en">Specific (Principal) profile</vCard:label>
            <vCard:label>Profil specific (principal)</vCard:label>
            <vCard:value>Etnografie</vCard:value>
            <vCard:label>Profil general</vCard:label>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dc:subject>
        <dc:title>"Odaia Bunicii" - Centrul Folcloric Grădiniţa, Galicea Mare</dc:title>
        <vCard:hasCategory>
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Info/Category/">
            <opendata:MainCategory xml:lang="en">Museum</opendata:MainCategory>
            <opendata:MainCategory>Muzeu</opendata:MainCategory>
            <vCard:category xml:lang="en"></vCard:category>
            <vCard:category>Muzeu Comunal</vCard:category>
          </rdf:Description>
        </vCard:hasCategory>
        <dcterms:description>
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Info/Description/">
            <opendata:Historic xml:lang="en"></opendata:Historic>
            <opendata:Historic></opendata:Historic>
            <dcterms:abstract xml:lang="en"></dcterms:abstract>
            <dcterms:abstract></dcterms:abstract>
            <dcterms:description xml:lang="en"></dcterms:description>
            <dcterms:description>Centrul folcloric al grădiniţei Galicea Mare este situat în incinta Grădiniţei nr.1, structură a Şcolii Gimnaziale Galicea Mare, judeţul Dolj, pe drumul european E56. Pentru a readuce la viaţă şi a reînvia atât tradiţiile cât şi portul popular românesc, a luat naştere „Odaia bunicii”, un loc in care obiectele prind viaţă şi creează o atmosferă caldă, plina de dragostea ţaranilor de altadată. Expoziţia permanentă, deschisă în 2016, este concepută într-o manieră tradiţională, fiecare obiect aşteptând să fie folosit pentru a-şi arata maiestria, astfel: patul cu tablii de lemn şi saltea de paie aşteaptă să odihnească omul, măsuţa din lemn şi scaunelele aşteaptă cu nerăbdare să fie servită cina, dar şi războiul ţăranesc unde femeile ţeseau macate ne reamintesc nouă, celor mari, şi îi învaţă pe cei mici despre obiceiurile şi tradiţiile româneşti de altădată.</dcterms:description>
            <opendata:Relevance xml:lang="en">Local</opendata:Relevance>
            <opendata:Relevance>Locală</opendata:Relevance>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:description>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dcterms:description>
    <dbPedia:Building>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Building/">
        <dbPedia:HistoricBuilding></dbPedia:HistoricBuilding>
        <dcterms:abstract xml:lang="en"></dcterms:abstract>
        <dcterms:abstract></dcterms:abstract>
        <dc:identifier></dc:identifier>
        <dc:type xml:lang="en">Building</dc:type>
        <dc:type>Cladire</dc:type>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dbPedia:Building>
    <opendata:MuseumTour>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Tour/">
        <vCard:hasCalendarRequest xml:lang="en">Unspecified</vCard:hasCalendarRequest>
        <vCard:hasCalendarRequest>luni-vineri 8:00-13:00</vCard:hasCalendarRequest>
        <opendata:VirtualTour></opendata:VirtualTour>
      </rdf:Description>
    </opendata:MuseumTour>
    <opendata:Contact>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Contact/">
        <vCard:url>
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Contact/URI/">
            <opendata:SocialMediaUri>
              <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Contact/URI/SocialMediaUri/">
                <vCard:label>Link-uri social media.</vCard:label>
                <vCard:hasValue></vCard:hasValue>
              </rdf:Description>
            </opendata:SocialMediaUri>
            <opendata:CimecUri>
              <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Contact/URI/CimecUri/">
                <vCard:label>Link-ul catre portalul CIMEC.</vCard:label>
                <vCard:hasValue>http://ghidulmuzeelor.cimec.ro/id.asp?k=2030&amp;-„Odaia-bunicii”-Centrul-folcloric-Gradinita,-Galicea-Mare-GALICEA-MARE-Dolj</vCard:hasValue>
              </rdf:Description>
            </opendata:CimecUri>
            <opendata:WebUri>
              <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Contact/URI/WebUri/">
                <vCard:label>Link-ul catre site-ul muzeului.</vCard:label>
                <vCard:hasValue></vCard:hasValue>
              </rdf:Description>
            </opendata:WebUri>
          </rdf:Description>
        </vCard:url>
        <vCard:Individual>
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Contact/Individual/">
            <opendata:Employee>
              <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Contact/Individual/Employee/">
                <vCard:hasName>Gologan Veronica</vCard:hasName>
                <vCard:hasRole>Profesor</vCard:hasRole>
              </rdf:Description>
            </opendata:Employee>
            <opendata:Manager>
              <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Contact/Individual/Manager/">
                <vCard:hasName>Văduva Cristian</vCard:hasName>
                <vCard:hasRole>Director</vCard:hasRole>
              </rdf:Description>
            </opendata:Manager>
          </rdf:Description>
        </vCard:Individual>
        <vCard:hasEmail></vCard:hasEmail>
        <vCard:hasTelephone>
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Contact/Telephone/">
            <vCard:Fax>
              <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Contact/Telephone/Fax/">
                <vCard:rev></vCard:rev>
                <vCard:value></vCard:value>
              </rdf:Description>
            </vCard:Fax>
            <vCard:Work>
              <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Contact/Telephone/Work/">
                <vCard:rev></vCard:rev>
                <vCard:value>0251.316.006; 0762.278.850</vCard:value>
              </rdf:Description>
            </vCard:Work>
          </rdf:Description>
        </vCard:hasTelephone>
      </rdf:Description>
    </opendata:Contact>
    <dcterms:spatials>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Spatials/">
        <vCard:hasAddress>
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Spatials/Address/">
            <vCard:postal-code>207270</vCard:postal-code>
            <vCard:region>Dolj</vCard:region>
            <dbPedia:AdministrativeRegion>Galicea Mare</dbPedia:AdministrativeRegion>
            <vCard:hasLocality>
              <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Spatials/Locality/">
                <opendata:Siruta></opendata:Siruta>
                <vCard:locality>Galicea Mare</vCard:locality>
              </rdf:Description>
            </vCard:hasLocality>
            <vCard:street-address>Str. Calafatului nr. 10</vCard:street-address>
          </rdf:Description>
        </vCard:hasAddress>
        <opendata:Access xml:lang="en"></opendata:Access>
        <opendata:Access></opendata:Access>
        <vCard:hasGeo>
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/resource/_Odaia_Bunicii-Centrul_Folcloric_Gradinita_Galicea_Mare_Dolj/Spatials/GeoPos/">
            <vCard:longitude>23.3</vCard:longitude>
            <vCard:latitude>44.1</vCard:latitude>
            <vCard:label>Localitate</vCard:label>
          </rdf:Description>
        </vCard:hasGeo>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dcterms:spatials>
  </dbPedia:Museum>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Why do you have the same `FILTER` three times? That is redundant

Comment: And the operator is called `OPTIONAL`. To be honest, it's not clear what you did with the `OPTIONAL` as you didn't show the query that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better answer...

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?o ?museum_res ?locality ?calendar ?category ?importanta
FROM <http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/repo/context/TTT>
WHERE { 
 {
   ?museum_res ?p ?o.
   ?e dc:title ?title.
   ?a vCard:locality ?locality.
   ?b vCard:category ?category.
   ?c vCard:hasCalendarRequest ?calendar.
   ?d openDataP:Relevance ?importanta.
   FILTER (
     UCASE(?o) = UCASE("http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Museum") && 
     contains(?title, "Odaia") &&
     contains(?e, ?museum_res) &&
     contains(?a, ?museum_res) && langMatches(lang(?locality),"") &&
     contains(?b, ?museum_res) && langMatches(lang(?category),"") &&
     contains(?c, ?museum_res) && langMatches(lang(?calendar),"") &&
     contains(?d, ?museum_res) &&langMatches(lang(?importanta),"")
   )
 }
}
ORDER BY ?museum_res
LIMIT 1200
```

Comment: It's the same useless SPARQL query. No triple pattern shares a variable with another triple pattern. See `?a vCard:locality ?locality.
   ?b vCard:category ?category.` What do you think it does?

Answer (score -1):

After 3-4 hours I found the solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?locality ?category ?calendar ?importanta
FROM <http://opendata.cs.pub.ro/repo/context/ilie>
WHERE { 
 ?a vCard:locality ?locality. FILTER (regex(?a, "odaia_bunicii", "i")).
 ?b vCard:category ?category. FILTER (regex(?b, "odaia_bunicii", "i")).
 ?c vCard:hasCalendarRequest ?calendar. FILTER (regex(?c, "odaia_bunicii", "i")).
 ?d openDataP:Relevance ?importanta. FILTER (regex(?d, "odaia_bunicii", "i")).
}
```

Comment: A solution for what? That is anything, but not a solution: None of the triple patterns in the query is connected with another, i.e. share a variable. That means, it return the cartesian product of all, I don't think that this is a useful query.

Comment: May you help me with a query answer because I don't understand very much?

Comment: @AKSW I posted a new answer... May you tell me if that is good?

Comment: Come on, it's the same problem. None of the triple patterns shares a variable. I don't understand what you're doing. Do you know what a triple pattern is? And what a join is? If so, a join is done on a shared variable between two or more triple patterns.